# Changing Collation did not effect on million rows of a table in SQL Server 2012 Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, collation

I have an `Android`Project in which I have to connect to `SQL Server 2012`.
I use `JTDS` as an Adapter to connect to DB.

I had collation issue to connect to this DB and read some fields and data.
So I changed the collation from `Persian` to `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS`, so I could connect and read some data from satisfied table of DB.

Now I want to connect to a table which has 28,000,000 rows.
I could not, and I did not determined the reason.

I tried and googled hard, and even asked question here, and with the help of my friends here, found the problem.

When I select from the table with 28,000,000 rows, it could not and give me this in Logcat:

> java.sql.SQLException: The statement failed because column 'Latitude'
>   (ID=0) uses collation Persian_100_CI_AI

But when I go to DB Properties, this is what I see:

[image]

It seems that the change collation could not effect on this table( Maybe cause of row index)
The question is what can i do?
I can select from another tables that have 60 rows.
But can not from this table.

Comment: Did you tried to change the collation in the select statement?

Comment: No, could you give a sample?

Comment: Data type for the problem column?

Comment: @Jarrg : varchar(25),varchar(10), varchar(10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Collation like Below in the select statement

`SELECT` 'ColumnName' `COLLATE` 'Collation Name' `From` Table

Example:

`SELECT` EmpName `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
`FROM` Employee

Comment: I did this, but it takes so much time.

Comment: yes it should because you have lot of records in your table. try to add the collated column in the index

Comment: And it says : Invalid column name ! in Lofcat.
However when copy and run my select statement from android-studio into SQL Server management studio it returns my values.
I use :  Latin1_General_100_CI_AS

Comment: Thx Bro,
It works.
Thx alot.
Invalid column name warning was my mistake.

Comment: you are welcome. you can up-vote the answer if it give solution to you :)

Comment: I do not have reputation yet.
I will as i get enough reputation.

Comment: If you are using that field in WHERE clause it will take too much time as it might not use index because of COLLATE, so if you can, add another column with correct collation and use that column.